# SQLite tables in apps with data before installation in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am doing an Android app in which I need to store data while creating an app. I want to do that with the help of SQLite. I need to use the data after installing it. I know that I can retrieve the data after installing. I need to know how can I keep the data in SQLite tables at the time of development, so that I can use the data that is stored after installation.

Is there any other way to achieve this other than SQLite?

Comment: So you would like to have a table with data preinstalled on the device when your app gets deployed?

Comment: yes, table with data should be preinstalled